# How to run Junit tests from command line on windows with no package?

Tags: java, testing, junit, path, classpath

I have a folder(which is where I am running all commands) called `learning`. Inside this folder, I have two files, one is called `Driver.java` which is a simple main class with a simple hello world method. The other file is `DriverTest.java` which has this code as shown below.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DriverTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Apart from this I have JUnit 4.13-beta jar inside the same `learning` folder.

Now I open command line in windows and go to `learning` folder location and run this command.

```
javac -cp junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;hamcrest-core-2.1-rc4.jar;. *.java
```

It didn't give me any errors, hence it has compiled both `Driver` and `DriverTest` java files.

Now I am trying to run the JUnit test using this command.

```
java -cp junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;hamcrest-core-2.1-rc4.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore DriverTest
```

But I am getting this error:

```
JUnit version 4.13-beta-1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
        at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:77)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:116)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
```

Why is my `HamCrest` jar not found? Its right there in the same folder right?

Comment: are you running it from the good folder?

Comment: good folder? If you mean the same folder where all my code is in, yes. All these files and all commands are being run in the same folder. No packages whatsoever.

Comment: http://benjamintan.io/blog/2014/10/14/running-junit-test-from-the-command-line/
Have you compiled your code?

Comment: Yes. As I have mentioned in my question, I am using `javac -cp junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;. *.java` to compile my code. I can also see that both `Driver.class` and `DriverTest.class` files have been created after compilation step. Now am I missing any jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only added the current directory to the classpath for compilation. This needs to also be done for test invocation, ie. `;.` in windows  `:.` on linux

```
java -cp junit-4.13-beta-1.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore DriverTest
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I tried your solution and apparently JUnit requires another jar called hamcrest. I have updated my question with new commands that I am using to run javac or java. I am now getting a new error saying that hamcrest class is not found(as updated in the question).